# Gradle ошибка при создании проекта

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, gradle

Gradle в Idea выдает следующую ошибку.

```
Gradle 'week1' project refresh failed
    Error:Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Gradle последней версии скачаный с оф. сайта(2.12).
ОС Ubuntu 15.10.
Idea 2016.1.1.
Все установил, переменную GRADLE_HOME тоже. как устанавливать и прописывать смотрел в гайдах и статьях.

через apt-get install gradle тоже установил, прописал гредл хом к нему,   но идея писала что неверный каталог для гредла. (при том что сам гредл этим способом установился нормально и на `gradle -v` отвечал нормально и jdk видел нужную)

думал еще может прав каких не хватает пробовал распаковывать скачанный архив в домашнюю директорию - тоже тщетно. помогите плиз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была не с Гитом в целом, а его интеграции в Идею.
В настройках гредла в идее `service derectory path` был указан не тот. Я указал `/home/den/.gradle` (где den - имя пользователя в Ubuntu)и заработало.